Should I create interfaces for each entity, or should I use plain classes?
I’m currently creating a class diagram to develop an application following the “Clean Architecture” guidelines by Robert C. Martin. I’m unsure about how to structure the “Entity” component, particularly in one specific aspect: Should I create interfaces for each entity, or should I use plain classes?
On one hand, if I use interfaces, they help ensure the correct typing of method parameters and return values. I could also potentially take advantage of the abstraction provided by interfaces to easily swap out any of my entity classes with future versions.
On the other hand, it seems that the “Use Case” component directly depends on the plain “Entity” classes, so creating interfaces for them might not be as beneficial.
It doesn’t help that in Clean Architecture, Robert C. Martin states that the “Entity” component should be the most abstract layer.
Does this mean I should use plain classes in the “Use Case” component, or does “abstract” simply refer to high-level policy in this context? In other words, does "abstract" not literally mean abstract classes or interfaces?
Thanks in advance!

What language will the app be written in?

It will be written in PHP

"In other words, does "abstract" not literally mean abstract classes or interfaces" - that's correct, it does not; as you said, it refers to high-level policies captured by the code at the core of the application (as opposed to the outer layer code that contains the more low-level details of how things actually get done at the "edges" of the application). That said, you can have, if needed, interfaces that are called by the outer layer, or an interface that a class in the outer layer implements (dependency inversion). Just don't create them by default, up front, that can create problems.

Thank you @FilipMilovanović . That cleared things for me

You should use plain classes for your entities.
The Clean Architecture approach essentially means that you have your most fundamental, high level, generic "things" at the core. These things interact with each other, but not with anything outside of this core. The classes in your core are your entities. They encapsulate data and behaviour, but not that the data is persisted, let alone how it is persisted.
Since the entities shouldn't depend on anything outside of the entity layer, this layer doesn't need to have any interfaces.
The entity layer should be the most stable layer of your application, in the sense that changes that occur outside of the entity layer should not cause changes inside of the entity layer.
The "Use Cases" layer is one layer "outside" of the entity layer. Use Cases allow the world to trigger the behaviours of your entities. A Use Case will always trigger the same behaviours on the same entities and as such, can depend on concrete implementations of the entities. A Use Case will know that data is persisted, but not how. Because of that, the Use Case layer needs to define interfaces that specify its persistence requirements (where "persistence" isn't just your database, but also your event bus, external API's, etc).
The implementations of these interfaces that are defined in the Use Case layer, are part of the "Interface Adapters" layer (thats what Robert calls it on https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html - other articles may use different names).
This is the layer that has all the code that interacts with the outside world. It will often do this via some library or framework, acting as an adapter that makes this library fit with what your use cases need.
Now, if we look at the Use Cases layer and the Interface Adapters layer, we'll see something that is somewhat different from what half the internet seems to describe. We see that the interface it defined near its consumers, instead of having the interface and its implementation next to each other. This approach may seem odd at first if you're not used to it, but if you think about where you would place the second concrete implementation of an interface, you'll quickly see that there is nothing special about that first implementation, so there is no good reason it should be the one that gets to be in the same package as the interface itself.
To also answer your last question, "what does Robert C Martin mean by 'abstract'", in this case, it means "without application specific implementation details", like how things are stored, what events need to be dispatched or what encoding the API client expects.

Thank you Jory, that cleared things a lot. I was really confused by what abstract would mean for the Entity Layer. Especially, as you pointed out, that Robert C. Martin seems to use interfaces to force implementation from the outlet layers to comply with inner layers interfaces.

So the two things didn't seem to add up. Specifying that "abstract" didn't mean "interface" or "abstract" class helped a lot. Even more after reading about the "Stable Abstraction Principle" earlier in the book.

Re "seems to use interfaces to force implementation from the outlet layers to comply with inner layer interfaces": The lower right part of the first image on https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html nicely shows that, and the "Crossing boundaries" section on that page goes into some more detail, if you want to read it in Martin's words.
